# changes not showing in field in ncurses

Tags: c++, field, ncurses

I have a ncurses program which is a login menu and I use field for username and password.
The problem is that when I type something in the fields, characters register but do not show in terminal. In other word if you execute the code blow and type something, you won't be able to see it in terminal but if you push F2, you could see  that the characters were registered.
Here is my code:
**test.cpp**

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <form.h>
#include <menu.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class WelcomeMenu {
private:
  int _row; // number of rows of the terminal
  int _col; // number of columns of the terminal
public:
  WelcomeMenu();
  ~WelcomeMenu();
  void welcomeBox();
  void loginMenu();
  void registerMenu();
};

WelcomeMenu::WelcomeMenu(){
  initscr();
  noecho();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, true);
  int row, col;
  getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);   /* get the number of rows and columns */
  this->_row = row; this->_col = col;
  loginMenu();
}

WelcomeMenu::~WelcomeMenu(){
  refresh();
  endwin();
}

/*
 * This is useful because ncurses fill fields blanks with spaces.
 */
char* trim_whitespaces(char *str)
{
  char *end;

  // trim leading space
  while(isspace(*str))
    str++;

  if(*str == 0) // all spaces?
    return str;

  // trim trailing space
  end = str + strnlen(str, 128) - 1;

  while(end > str && isspace(*end))
    end--;

  // write new null terminator
  *(end+1) = '\0';

  return str;
}

void WelcomeMenu::loginMenu(){
  // erase();
  FORM *form;
  FIELD *fields[5];
  WINDOW *win_body, *win_form;

  int ch;

  win_body = newwin(24, 80, 0, 0);
  assert(win_body != NULL);
  box(win_body, 0, 0);
  win_form = derwin(win_body, 20, 78, 3, 1);
  assert(win_form != NULL);
  box(win_form, 0, 0);
  mvwprintw(win_body, 1, 2, "Press F1 to quit and F2 to print fields content");

  fields[0] = new_field(1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  fields[1] = new_field(1, 40, 0, 15, 0, 0);
  fields[2] = new_field(1, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0);
  fields[3] = new_field(1, 40, 2, 15, 0, 0);
  fields[4] = NULL;
  assert(fields[0] != NULL && fields[1] != NULL && fields[2] != NULL && fields[3] != NULL);

  set_field_buffer(fields[0], 0, "Username: ");
  set_field_buffer(fields[1], 0, "username");
  set_field_buffer(fields[2], 0, "Password: ");
  set_field_buffer(fields[3], 0, "password");

  set_field_opts(fields[0], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);
  set_field_opts(fields[1], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE);
  set_field_opts(fields[2], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);
  set_field_opts(fields[3], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE);

  set_field_back(fields[1], A_UNDERLINE);
  set_field_back(fields[3], A_UNDERLINE);

  form = new_form(fields);
  assert(form != NULL);
  set_form_win(form, win_form);
  set_form_sub(form, derwin(win_form, 18, 76, 1, 1));
  post_form(form);

  refresh();
  wrefresh(win_body);
  wrefresh(win_form);

  while ((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(1)){

    switch (ch) {
      case KEY_F(2):
        // Or the current field buffer won't be sync with what is displayed
        form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_FIELD);
        form_driver(form, REQ_PREV_FIELD);
        move(LINES-3, 2);

        for (int i = 0; fields[i]; i++) {
          printw("%s", trim_whitespaces(field_buffer(fields[i], 0)));

          if (field_opts(fields[i]) & O_ACTIVE)
            printw("\"\t");
          else
            printw(": \"");
        }

        refresh();
        pos_form_cursor(form);
        break;

      case KEY_DOWN:
        form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_FIELD);
        form_driver(form, REQ_END_LINE);
        break;

      case KEY_UP:
        form_driver(form, REQ_PREV_FIELD);
        form_driver(form, REQ_END_LINE);
        break;

      case KEY_LEFT:
        form_driver(form, REQ_PREV_CHAR);
        break;

      case KEY_RIGHT:
        form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_CHAR);
        break;

      // Delete the char before cursor
      case KEY_BACKSPACE:
      case 127:
        form_driver(form, REQ_DEL_PREV);
        break;

      // Delete the char under the cursor
      case KEY_DC:
        form_driver(form, REQ_DEL_CHAR);
        break;

      default:
        form_driver(form, ch);
        break;
    }
  }

  wrefresh(win_form);

  unpost_form(form);
  free_form(form);
  free_field(fields[0]);
  free_field(fields[1]);
  free_field(fields[2]);
  free_field(fields[3]);
  delwin(win_form);
  delwin(win_body);
}

int main(){
  WelcomeMenu * myConWin = new WelcomeMenu();
  delete myConWin;
  return 0;
}
```

you can compile it like: `g++ -lncurses -lform test.cpp`

Thank you in advance for your response

Comment: Any reason you use C header files for a C++ program ? IMHO, you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem with the example is that it does not provide for displaying the characters.  In ncurses, that would be done using the [**`form_driver`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_driver.3x.html) function:

> **form_driver**

```
   Once a form has been posted (displayed), you should funnel input events
   to it through form_driver.  This routine has three major input cases:

   o   The input is a form navigation request.  Navigation  request  codes
       are constants defined in <form.h>, which are distinct from the key-
       and character codes returned by wgetch(3x).

   o   The input is a printable character.   Printable  characters  (which
       must  be positive, less than 256) are checked according to the pro-
       gram's locale settings.

   o   The input is the KEY_MOUSE special key  associated  with  an  mouse
       event.
```

Making your program use **`form_driver`** would involve some reorganization of the program, moving that switch-statement into a function which can be called from the form-driver.

The ncurses examples include a few using [`form_driver`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_driver.3x.html#h3-form_driver).  You might want to read through the test-code, seeing how the [basic loop](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/b90b0e1a9e2edd957d829d42c3abde26921d4f07/test/ncurses.c#L6750)

```
 while (!finished) {
     switch (form_driver(form, c = form_virtualize(form, w))) {
     case E_OK:
          MvAddStr(5, 57, field_buffer(secure, 1));
          clrtoeol();
          refresh();
          break;
     case E_UNKNOWN_COMMAND:
          finished = my_form_driver(form, c);
          break;
     default:
          beep();
          break;
     }
```

uses its `form_virtualize` function to read characters (or form-requests).  The printable characters that you are (not) seeing are handled by **`form_driver`** which updates the current field on the form.  You can manipulate the field-buffer and do other special things as done in `form_virtualize`, but updating fields in the form is why you would use **`form_driver`**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `echo` and `noecho` to turn echoing on/off. You could bake that part into an input function if you'd like:

```
#include <memory>

struct input_context {
    input_context() {
        echo();       // echo typed characters
        curs_set(1);  // show the cursor
    }
    ~input_context() {
        curs_set(0);  // hide the cursor
        noecho();     // turn off echoing
    }
};

std::string get_string(WINDOW* win, size_t len) {
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);
    input_context dummy;
    if(wgetnstr(win, buf.get(), len) != ERR) return std::string{buf.get()};
    return {};
}
```

Note 1: You should only use `new`/`delete` (and `new[]`/`delete[]`) when all other options have been depleted. In your `main`, you could just replace the dynamic creation of your `WelcomeMenu` with an automatic variable:

```
int main(){
  WelcomeMenu myConWin;
}
```

Note 2: Use `nullptr`, not `NULL`.

```
fields[4] = nullptr; // was NULL
```

Note 3: As stated by @kebs in the comments, you should use the C++ versions of the header files:

```
#include <cassert>   // was assert.h
#include <cstdio>    // was stdio.h
#include <cstdlib>   // was stdlib.h
```

Comment: The C++ headers are irrelevant for this example.  Actually `<stdio.h>` is redundant because `<curses.h>` includes it.

Comment: @ThomasDickey The stuff in the notes parts are just general advice.

Comment: Just as a general guideline, when someone posts a workable example, I'd test my suggestions before providing advice.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I usually do, but I admit that I wrote the function to OP:s previous question (that was deleted just when I was about to submit the answer). It worked well there but I failed in testing it using the updated code.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Now I've tested it, and the advices, and all worked just fine with this code too as far as I could see, even though it bypasses the form_driver. `wprintw(win_form, "enter test: "); wrefresh(win_form); auto s = get_string(win_form, 10); wprintw(win_form, "got: %s", s.c_str()); wrefresh(win_form);` What seemed to be the problem when you tested it?

Comment: Your approach also bypasses the operations on the field buffer, which is used in OP's question.