# ncurses set_field_buffer and a two-byte UTF-8 character

Tags: ncurses

How can I load the ncurses set_field_buffer with a two-byte UTF-8 character?

Some context. I am attempting to build an ncurses form to capture latitude and longitude numbers in degrees, minutes and seconds. In the spirit of standing on the shoulders of the giants, I have adapted this code: https://gist.github.com/alan-mushi/c8a6f34d1df18574f643. I have also:

- Added #include <locale.h> to the code.
- Added setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); to the code.
- Linked to ncurses, not ncursesw.

The following picture shows how the form turned out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5yFl.png)

That letter M after the 137 is the problem. It has to be the degrees sign (°).

I loaded all of the characters shown on the form using set_field_buffer. My code for that is:

```
set_field_buffer(fields[0], 0, "Site A:");
set_field_buffer(fields[1], 0, "w");        /* Station: n, s, w or e. */
set_field_buffer(fields[2], 0, "137");      /* Degrees */
set_field_buffer(fields[3], 0, "\u00B0");   /* Degrees symbol*/
set_field_buffer(fields[4], 0, "22");       /* Minutes */
set_field_buffer(fields[5], 0, "'");        /* Minutes symbol*/
set_field_buffer(fields[6], 0, "45.92");    /* Seconds */
set_field_buffer(fields[7], 0, "\u0022");   /* Seconds symbol*/
```

Although field 3 is set for "\u00B0", the letter M shows. Alan Mushi's code allows you to press F2 to see the contents of the buffers. The "\u00B0" is rendered as M-B. That suggests to me that set_field_buffer accepts two-byte UTF-8 characters but does not render them correctly. I cannot find a specification detailing what is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The call to [`setlocale`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) has to be **before** the `initscr` call.  Otherwise, ncurses will not use that information, and you will see the data presented that way:

> If the locale is not initialized, the library assumes  that  characters
> are  printable  as in ISO-8859-1, to work with certain legacy programs.
> You should initialize the locale and not rely on  specific  details  of
> the library when the locale has not been setup.

The bytes used for `\u00b0` are `\302` and `\260` (octal).  If you link with ***ncurses*** rather than ***ncursesw***, you will of course see an odd display, since the (narrow) ncurses library knows nothing about UTF-8. It relies upon the `<ctype.h>` macros such as `isprint` to tell it whether a character is printable in the current locale.  For GNU libc (and some others), those macros return false for all of the codes from `\177` to `\377`, making ***ncurses*** display those as a printable form described in the [`keyname`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-keyname_key_name) manpage.

> - Printable characters are displayed as themselves, e.g., a one-character string containing the key.
> - Control characters are displayed in the **`^X`** notation.
> - DEL (character 127) is displayed as **`^?`**.
> - *Values  above 128 are either meta characters (if the screen has not
>   been initialized, or if meta(3x) has been called with a TRUE parameter),  shown  in the **`M-X`** notation, or are displayed as themselves.*
>   In the latter case, the values may not be printable;  this  follows
>   the X/Open specification.

Though not emphasized in the manual page, `unctrl` and `keyname` give the same result for those characters.

The [`addch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) manpage alludes to this (mentioning `^X` because it is the most often encountered):

> If  *ch*  is  any  other  control  character, it is drawn in ***`^X`** notation*.
> Calling **`winch`** after adding a control  character  does  not  return  the
> character  itself, but instead returns the ^-representation of the control character.

Now, using ***ncursesw*** (because the manual page indicates this is required for a locale using "wide characters" such as Unicode):

[image: example of screen-output]

```
--- fields_magic.c.orig 2020-07-08 17:49:58.000000000 -0400
+++ fields_magic.c      2020-07-08 17:58:01.650425188 -0400
@@ -4,15 +4,16 @@
  * How to run:
  *     gcc -Wall -Werror -g -pedantic -o test fields_magic.c -lform -lncurses
  */
-#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>
-#include <ncurses/form.h>
+#include <curses.h>
+#include <form.h>
 #include <assert.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
+#include <locale.h>
 
 static FORM *form;
-static FIELD *fields[5];
+static FIELD *fields[15];
 static WINDOW *win_body, *win_form;
 
 /*
@@ -55,7 +56,7 @@
                        for (i = 0; fields[i]; i++) {
                                printw("%s", trim_whitespaces(field_buffer(fields[i], 0)));
 
-                               if (field_opts(fields[i]) & O_ACTIVE)
+                               if (field_opts(fields[i]) & (int) O_ACTIVE)
                                        printw("\"\t");
                                else
                                        printw(": \"");
@@ -102,10 +103,11 @@
        wrefresh(win_form);
 }
 
-int main()
+int main(void)
 {
        int ch;
 
+       setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        initscr();
        noecho();
        cbreak();
@@ -126,10 +128,13 @@
        fields[4] = NULL;
        assert(fields[0] != NULL && fields[1] != NULL && fields[2] != NULL && fields[3] != NULL);
 
-       set_field_buffer(fields[0], 0, "label1");
-       set_field_buffer(fields[1], 0, "val1");
-       set_field_buffer(fields[2], 0, "label2");
-       set_field_buffer(fields[3], 0, "val2");
+       set_field_buffer(fields[0], 0, "w");        /* Station: n, s, w or e. */
+       set_field_buffer(fields[1], 0, "137");      /* Degrees */
+       set_field_buffer(fields[2], 0, "\u00B0");   /* Degrees symbol*/
+       set_field_buffer(fields[3], 0, "22");       /* Minutes */
+       set_field_buffer(fields[4], 0, "'");        /* Minutes symbol*/
+       set_field_buffer(fields[5], 0, "45.92");    /* Seconds */
+       set_field_buffer(fields[6], 0, "\"");       /* Seconds symbol*/
 
        set_field_opts(fields[0], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);
        set_field_opts(fields[1], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE);
```

That `"\u0022"` is not a valid character string (the compiler can tell you that).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment. In fact the call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` is before `initscr()` and the locale on my Debian Bullseye installation is set to UTF-8. I compile the code linked to ncurses and form.

As a sanity check, I'd be grateful if you would run my code and verify that the `\u00B0` character does not render correctly.

My code follows:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <form.h>
#include <cassert>   // Was assert.h See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127743/changes-not-showing-in-field-in-ncurses
#include <cstdlib>   // Was stdlib.h
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>

static FORM *form;
static FIELD *fields[11];
static WINDOW *win_body, *win_form;


/*
 * This is useful because ncurses fill fields blanks with spaces.
 */
static char* trim_whitespaces(char *str) {
    char *end;

    // trim leading space
    while(isspace(*str))
        str++;

    if(*str == 0) // all spaces?
        return str;

    // trim trailing space
    end = str + strnlen(str, 128) - 1;

    while(end > str && isspace(*end))
        end--;

    // write new null terminator
    *(end+1) = '\0';

    return str;
}

static void driver(int ch) {
    int i;

    switch (ch) {
        case KEY_F(2):
            // Or the current field buffer won't be sync with what is displayed
            form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_FIELD);
            form_driver(form, REQ_PREV_FIELD);
            move(LINES-3, 2);

            for (i = 0; fields[i]; i++) {
                printw("%s", trim_whitespaces(field_buffer(fields[i], 0)));

                if (field_opts(fields[i]) & O_ACTIVE)
                    printw("\"\t");
                else
                    printw(": \"");
            }

            refresh();
            pos_form_cursor(form);
            break;

        case KEY_DOWN:
            form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_FIELD);
            form_driver(form, REQ_END_LINE);
            break;

        case KEY_UP:
            form_driver(form, REQ_PREV_FIELD);
            form_driver(form, REQ_END_LINE);
            break;

        case KEY_LEFT:
            form_driver(form, REQ_PREV_CHAR);
            break;

        case KEY_RIGHT:
            form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_CHAR);
            break;

        // Delete the char before cursor
        case KEY_BACKSPACE:
        case 127:
            form_driver(form, REQ_DEL_PREV);
            break;

        // Delete the char under the cursor
        case KEY_DC:
            form_driver(form, REQ_DEL_CHAR);
            break;

        default:
            form_driver(form, ch);
            break;
    }

    wrefresh(win_form);
}

int main() {
    int ch;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    win_body = newwin(24, 80, 0, 0);
    assert(win_body != NULL);
    box(win_body, 0, 0);
    win_form = derwin(win_body, 20, 78, 3, 1);
    assert(win_form != NULL);
    box(win_form, 0, 0);
    mvwprintw(win_body, 1, 2, "Press F1 to quit and F2 to print fields content");

    fields[0] = new_field(1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0);    // Site A:
    fields[1] = new_field(1, 1, 0, 9, 0, 0);    // Station: n, s, w or e.
    fields[2] = new_field(1, 3, 0, 12,0, 0);    // Degrees
    fields[3] = new_field(1, 1, 0, 15,0, 0);    // Degrees symbol
    fields[4] = new_field(1, 2, 0, 17,0, 0);    // Minutes
    fields[5] = new_field(1, 1, 0, 19,0, 0);    // Minutes symbol
    fields[6] = new_field(1, 5, 0, 21,0, 0);    // Seconds
    fields[7] = new_field(1, 1, 0, 26,0, 0);    // Seconds symbol

    fields[8] = new_field(1, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0);
    fields[9] = new_field(1, 40, 2, 15, 0, 0);

    fields[10] = NULL;
    assert(fields[0] != NULL && fields[1] != NULL && fields[2] != NULL && fields[3] != NULL && fields[4] != NULL && fields[5] != NULL && fields[6] != NULL && fields[7] != NULL && fields[8] != NULL && fields[9] != NULL);

    set_field_buffer(fields[0], 0, "Site A:");
    set_field_buffer(fields[1], 0, "w");        // Station: n, s, w or e.
    set_field_buffer(fields[2], 0, "137");      // Degrees
    set_field_buffer(fields[3], 0, "\u00B0");   // Degrees symbol
    set_field_buffer(fields[4], 0, "22");       // Minutes
    set_field_buffer(fields[5], 0, "'");        // Minutes symbol
    set_field_buffer(fields[6], 0, "45.92");    // Seconds
    set_field_buffer(fields[7], 0, "\u0022");   // Seconds symbol

    set_field_buffer(fields[8], 0, "Site B:");
    set_field_buffer(fields[9], 0, "");

    set_field_opts(fields[0], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);
    set_field_opts(fields[1], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE | O_BLANK | O_STATIC);       // Station: n, s, w or e.
    set_field_opts(fields[2], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE | O_BLANK | O_STATIC);       // Degrees
    set_field_opts(fields[3], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);                       // Degrees symbol
    set_field_opts(fields[4], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE | O_BLANK | O_STATIC);       // Minutes
    set_field_opts(fields[5], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);                           // Minutes symbol
    set_field_opts(fields[6], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE | O_BLANK | O_STATIC);       // Seconds
    set_field_opts(fields[7], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);                           // Seconds symbol

    set_field_opts(fields[8], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_AUTOSKIP);
    set_field_opts(fields[9], O_VISIBLE | O_PUBLIC | O_EDIT | O_ACTIVE);

    set_field_back(fields[1], A_UNDERLINE); // Station: n, s, w or e.
    set_field_back(fields[2], A_UNDERLINE); // Degrees
    set_field_back(fields[4], A_UNDERLINE); // Minutes
    set_field_back(fields[6], A_UNDERLINE); // Seconds

    set_field_back(fields[9], A_UNDERLINE);

    form = new_form(fields);
    assert(form != NULL);
    set_form_win(form, win_form);
    set_form_sub(form, derwin(win_form, 18, 76, 1, 1));
    post_form(form);

    refresh();
    wrefresh(win_body);
    wrefresh(win_form);

    while ((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
        driver(ch);

    unpost_form(form);
    free_form(form);
    free_field(fields[0]);
    free_field(fields[1]);
    free_field(fields[2]);
    free_field(fields[3]);
    free_field(fields[4]);
    free_field(fields[5]);
    free_field(fields[6]);
    free_field(fields[7]);
    free_field(fields[8]);
    free_field(fields[9]);
    free_field(fields[10]);
    delwin(win_form);
    delwin(win_body);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On some distributions there is a possibility to link application with ncurses and and ncursesw libraries. For unicode you need to use ncursesw library. `gcc pager.c -o pspg -ggdb -lncursesw`

Comment: It's unlikely that he will get a workable program linking against **both** ncurses and ncursesw.  By the way, I already gave a correct answer for this.  I'll attach a screenshot showing that the symbol displays properly, and a diff from the original program showing the changes made.

Comment: @ PavelStehule. If I link to 'ncursesw', the layout of the forms is garbled. After pressing F2, the \u00B0 character does not render correctly.

Comment: @ThomasDickie. In your diff the #includes are not complete. May I know what you intended there? After editing the code to include your diffs, the \u00B0 character still does not show correctly when I use the following includes:

#include <ncurses.h>
#include <form.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>

Comment: @ThomasDickie Thank you for your comments to date. I am grateful for your explanation about how ncurses works with wide characters. However there is still something I'm missing as I now see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/No6xC.png

Note that, after pressing F2, the degrees symbol is rendered correctly. I suspect I have omitted something in the main part of the code surrounding the setting of the form's fields.